# Question about pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, pending-transactions

I am running loads of transactions in a private POA network, even a few per seconds. The nonces are being managed by a specific service.
The issue I encountered was that one sealer somehow didn't manage to mine a transaction (it wasn't reverted) and the next 40-50 transactions were staying in pending tx pool, due to the nonce gap.
My question is what would `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender_address, 'pending')` return in this case? The nonce of the unprocessed transaction or `NUMBER_OF_MINED_TX_FOR_SENDER + PENDING_TX_COUNT_FOR_SENDER`? Or something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to split your question into 2 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a nonce gap, the call will not take those transactions into consideration.

This means, that a call to:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender_address, 'pending')
```

Will return `NUMBER_OF_MINED_TX_FOR_SENDER + PENDING_TX_COUNT_FOR_SENDER` only for the transactions that have sequential nonces, without any gap.

But it will take into consideration the not mined transactions that have sequential, non-gapped nonce.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this.